# Interpret This Code

Tags: discussion, tags, title

So, those on student/enthusiast side of the house often find snippets of code (open source projects, homework assignments, work related, etc.) that can be a bit confusing and need interpreting help at times.  Seems SO could be a good fit for such an occasion.  In doing this very thing myself, I had a second thought about how I might title the posting.  I don't recall any titles such as "Interpret This Code" when browsing questions.  Of course many of the questions do involve help with interpreting in some form or fashion, but none strictly titled "Interpret This Code" with tags indicating some category or language that is involved.  So I ask, **is it Ok to make a title postings like "Interpret This Code"?  If so, is there anything wrong with loads of questions that have the aforementioned title?**  Just curios.  **Sometime you just don't know enough about the code to give a meaningful title.  So why not use the title given for this posting?**

In doing a quick scan of questions and recent history questions, I did not recall seeing the title.  Of course, **my sampling could be bad.**

Comment: The type of question you seem to be suggesting here should seem clearly against the site FAQ regarding what kinds of questions should be asked.

Comment: The very definition of "too localized". Such a question/answer would have absolutely no use outside of that *one instance*.

Comment: Wow, I got beat up pretty good.  Oh well, sometimes it costs to help difine a line, or just make that line a bit clearer.  To the future of new SO'ers.

Answer (score 10):

> is it Ok to make a title postings like "Interpret This Code"?

No, that's not okay.  The title of your question should at least be searchable.  It should tell people specifically what the question is about.

> Sometime you just don't know enough about the code to give a meaningful title. So why not use the title given for this posting?

"I am not able to rightly apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question."  Why are you asking a question about code you don't understand enough to give it a proper title?  What are you trying to *do*?  Your business requirements should precede any code you write.  If you don't understand your own requirements, how can you expect anyone to answer questions about it?

Comment: Requirements is a good rule of thumb to operate on.  I guess I was thinking if the tags can cover the nature of the the question, restating them in the title was redundant.

Answer (score 5):

We do not want a flood of questions that are simply asking to *explain* a piece of code.

If you want to know what a given snippet of code does, run it. We're here to offer assistance in fixing code, or perhaps explaining why code might very well be unfixable without changing directions. We help you solve programming problems you are presently facing. Just explaining code blocks you might find in various projects or blogs is not what we do.